# Controller action alias in ASP.NET MVC CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core

I have an action called **/Telemetries/Page2** . I wish that **/Telemetries/Index** was an alias of the aforementioned action.

I added to **startup.cs/Configure** the following lines:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "alias_route_home",
                template: "Telemetries/Index",
                defaults: new { controller = "Telemetries", action = "Page2" });
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "alias_route_events",
                template: "Events/Index",
                defaults: new { controller = "Events", action = "Pagina5" });
        });
```

and it works!

Comment: Is this MVC4 or MVC Core, you have tagged both? Also, please show how you are doing your routing now. Finally, you know that multiple URLs that point to the same page are bad for Google SEO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "alias_route",
                template: "Telemetries/Index",
                defaults: new { controller = "Telemetries", action = "Page2" });
});
```

Comment: Martin, in addition to the route, is there a way to create the action index respond with the action page2?

Comment: I do not know an other way, routing is supposed to be used for such tasks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57628092/asp-net-core-controller-action-aliasing