# ASP.NET CORE Controller action aliasing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core

In my view layer i have the following controller call :

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Telemetries" asp-action="Pagina2">Home Page</a></li>
```

I want to create a Index action I can put in the call as follows :

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Telemetries" asp-action="Index">Home Page</a></li>
```

How can i do?

Comment: you need to specify method="your method type"  also check if there is **any asp-controller** and **asp-action** property is used in your form tag

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil : Could you please explain me better, perhaps with an example? Thanks, Simone

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2